# Laravel file downloaded from Dropbox with Filesystem

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox

I'm trying to download my files stored in Dropbox. After many searches on google found some solutions but nothing working for me.

Here is the code I have tried to download the file

```
    $disk = 'dropbox';

    $file = Storage::disk($disk)->get('Apps/CordovaFast/sample-connection-1425502866/cordova.ios.js');

    return Storage::download($file);
```

But no luck 
The documentation of laravl mentioned this package for dropbox => https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox . This is what I am using.
After trying the code above following error occurred.

> File not found at path:  Platform: ..........

Comment: As far as I know, Laravel by its own doesn't support dropbox. What packages are you using to connect to dropbox API?

Comment: the documentation of laravel mentioned this package => https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox and I used it. It works fine as creating and uploading file but not the download.